# Create database and move mdf files to SQL default location

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I want to create a database in SQL from .mdf file present in a temp location say `C:\Temp`

I am using the following query

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\temp\temp.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\temp\temp.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

But I want the mdf and ldf files to be copied to the SQL default path`(C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\)` on attaching, as the temp location may get deleted or changed in the future.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to copy/move the files into the desired directory before attaching.
If you want it to be done completely from within SQL you will need to:

- Enable xp_cmdshell
- Execute a script like below:

  ```
  USE [master]
  GO
  DECLARE @result int
  EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell 'copy c:\temp\temp.mdf
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.mdf';
  IF (@result = 0)
      EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell 'copy c:\temp\temp.ldf
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.ldf';
      IF (@result = 0)
          CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
          (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.mdf'),
          (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.ldf')
          FOR ATTACH ;
          GO
      ELSE
          PRINT 'Failure'
  ELSE
      PRINT 'Failure'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error because of space in the directory path, use double quote.

```
USE [master]
GO
DECLARE @result int
EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell 'copy "c:\temp\temp.mdf" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.mdf"';

IF (@result = 0)
Begin
    EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell 'copy "c:\temp\temp.ldf" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.ldf"';
    IF (@result = 0)
    Begin
        CREATE DATABASE [Your_Database_Name] ON 
        (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.mdf'),
        (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\temp.ldf')
        FOR ATTACH ;
    End
    ELSE
        PRINT 'Failure'
End
ELSE
    PRINT 'Failure'
```